C# .NET 8 Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient how to avoid excessive files in the debug folder
Apologies - I am new to .NET core, I am very comfortable with .NET Framework.
For many years I have been using System.Data,Sqlclient to access Microsoft SQL Server database tables. It was easy, no additional packages, no additional library files.
Now I must update to use Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient, which appears to be provided by a NUGET package. I must be setting up/configuring incorrectly. When I compile (Windows Desktop Form app), the Debug folder is overloaded with library files. Is there anyway to refer to the library files to avoid the excess file duplication?
I was expecting just the EXE to be in the Debug folder.

There's more than one way to deploy your app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ but only "self contained" will be single .exe, and that will also include the framework libraries.

Including each specific version of each dependency you use is better than "dll hell".
